# Azure pipeline, last stage is skipped and I don't understand why ! Is there a limit on approvals or a limited time?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working on a pipeline running on a Windows Self Hosted agent.
I use a script in Stage1 that initialize a variable, I use the variable in a condition on Stage2 and Stage3.

If variable is true, Stage2 is ran, this stage as an environment with an approval.
If variable is false, Stage3 stage is ran.

In any case, Stage4 is ran.
This now works well but if Stage2 is ran, Stage5 is always skipped !

[image]

I don't understand why as the only dependency of Stage5 is Stage4 !

```
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: CompareFiles
        dependsOn: Build_Project
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - task: PowerShell@2
            name: compareFiles
            inputs:
              targetType: filePath
              filePath: '***\compareFileContent.ps1'

  - stage: ContinueWithApproval
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: eq( dependencies.Build.outputs['CompareFiles.compareFiles.filesAreEqual'], 'true' )
    jobs:
    - deployment: Continue
      environment: 'EnvironmentWithApproval'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: CmdLine@2
              inputs:
                script: '***'

  - stage: ContinueWithoutApproval
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: eq( dependencies.Build.outputs['CompareFiles.compareFiles.filesAreEqual'], 'false' )
    jobs:
    - deployment: Continue
      environment: 'EnvironmentWithoutApproval'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: CmdLine@2
              inputs:
                script: '***'


  - stage: DeployStaging
    dependsOn: 
    - ContinueWithApproval
    - ContinueWithoutApproval
    condition: or(eq( dependencies.ContinueWithApproval.result, 'Succeeded' ), eq( dependencies.ContinueWithoutApproval.result, 'Succeeded' ))
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy_To_Staging
      environment: 'Name ST'
      strategy:
           runOnce:
             deploy:
               steps:
                - task: PowerShell@2
                  inputs:
                    targetType: filePath
                    filePath: '***.ps1'

  - stage: DeployPreProd
    dependsOn: 
    - DeployStaging
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy_To_Preprod
      environment: 'Name PP'
      strategy:
           runOnce:
             deploy:
               steps:
                - task: PowerShell@2
                  inputs:
                    targetType: filePath
                    filePath: '***.ps1'
```

If variable is false, Stage3 is ran and then, Stage4 and Stage5 !!!

Oh! The environment on Stage5 also has an approval, can this be the issue ? A limit on the number of approvals ?

Thanks and regards,
Claude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approvals are on environment so this should not be an issue.

Try removing

```
dependsOn: 
- DeployStaging
```

From your 5th stage.  The default behavior is to depend on the previous stage.  I am wondering since dependsOn is being provided w/o a condition it is not skipping since the condition has not been provided.

Alternatively could add

```
succeeded()
```